# Commit on Bitbucket trigger synchronisation with Github repository?

Tags: git, azure, github, bitbucket

I'm using external Bitbucket repository and when i make a commit, i want to have all changes synchronised with Github repository. Is it possible?

I need it, because "azure web app" works well with github repo and doesn't work with external bitbucket repo.

Comment: Yes, problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Tyler T](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/444655). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can have one repository on your local machine and set it up to have multiple remotes. You can try this way:

```
# cd into the folder on your machine
# maybe the origin is set to Github, pull the latest changes

git pull origin master

# set Bitbucket as another remote named 'bitbucket'

git remote add bitbucket git@bitbucket.org:username/repo-name.git

# push the repo to the new remote 'bitbucket'

git push bitbucket master

# now the Bitbucket repo is up-to-date
```

Now, anytime you make changes and push to **Github (origin)**, you can `push` to the other **remote (bitbucket)** to keep them in sync. To use advanced solution, you can try Webhooks to sync them automatically.

You can refer to [How to sync a Bitbucket repo to a Github repo](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-sync-a-Bitbucket-repo-to-a-Github-repo/qaq-p/1000717) and [A BitBucket CI/CD Pipeline to Sync Branches With GitHub](https://betterprogramming.pub/a-bitbucket-ci-cd-pipeline-to-sync-branches-with-github-1c885cefe202)